PetaLinux 2023.2 - dbus X11 Dependency Issue (at do_rootfs Stage)
I'm developing a project using PetaLinux 2023.2(It is based on yocto langdale) with systemd as the init system. I've encountered an issue while trying to remove X11 from my system. I've removed x11 from DISTRO_FEATURES, but I'm still getting an error due to the dbus package's libx11 dependency.
The problem occurs at the do_rootfs stage, which suggests it might be a runtime dependency issue. The error message is as follows:
ERROR: petalinux-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages. Command '...' returned 100:
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbus-1 : Depends: libx11 (>= 1.8.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What's particularly confusing is that when I run

bitbake -g petalinux-image-minimal

, the resulting dependency graph shows no X11-related dependencies. Yet, this error still occurs at the do_rootfs stage.
When I examine the generated deb package, I see that dbus-launch has a dependency on libx11.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
